# Compile GO source code (on regular intervals)

Tags: go

I have a GO compiler available (i.e. installed in a dir `~/xxxx/bin/go`).

Suppose to call this version **GO.1**

I now clone the GO repository from GitHub (ex. into `~/yyyy/`)

Setting `$GOROOT_BOOTSTRAP=~/xxxx/` I can compile it
as `cd ~/yyyy/src && ./all.bash`
obtaining the GO binary in `~/yyyy/bin` (Suppose to call this **GO.2**)

I'd like now to use this new **GO.2** binary `~/yyyy/bin/go` to recompile its new source (`~/yyyy/src`) having a final 'good' **GO.3**

I cannot just set `$GOROOT_BOOTSTRAP` to `~/yyyy/` or play with some others env vars (at least I tried many attempts with no success).

The only way I've found to do this is:

1. copy  `~/yyyy/` (about 800MB!) onto `~/xxxx/` (so that **GO.2**
   overwrites **GO.1** and the `$GOROOT_BOOTSTRAP` is unchanged)
2. redo `cd ~/yyyy/src && ./all.bash`

This cannot be the expected behaviour.
I'd like to have the most up-to-date binary **GO.x** just with a `git pull && cd ./src && ./all.bash` and no much more than this.

Any hint is welcome.

Comment: Just keep a separate bootstrap binary in `GOROOT_BOOTSTRAP` (outside of `GOROOT`) and use that every time.

Comment: could you just run the binary at the location it lives instead of modifying your path, e.g. `~/yyyy/go build`

Comment: Thank you very much to all. The `go build` solution seems to fix my issue. Yes, I could keep a separate bootstrap bin, but it would miss all the new commits, maybe some are bug fixes, and I admit to be quite paranoid on this. Thanks a lot again

Comment: @basilest: new commits are irrelevant for the bootstrap compiler (unless you can't build at all), because you're building a new compiler each time, so all packages are always built by the latest compiler. `GOROOT_BOOTSTRAP` is only for bootstrapping, and nothing else.

Comment: @basilest: Would you be able to help my issue in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66306514/problem-building-the-go-compiler-from-source? Thx.